# ASP.NET MVC web application suddenly slows down queries and SQL Server : Closing and restarting browser helps

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC web application with IIS 8.5 and table adapters connected to SQL Server 2014.

Every now and then my SQL queries (event the most simpliest) suddenly slow down from 15ms to 36 seconds. If I run the same query via the SQL Server Managament Studio it's as slow as with the application. But as soon as I close the browser and restart the application everything works again ultra-fast (application and SQL Server Management Studio) for some time (until it suddenly slows down again).

Any hint what could cause this kind of thing?

Comment: Can you run your application and watch what's going on in SQL Profiler? To understand 100% that it isn't SQL problem.

Comment: Are you closing off and disposing of your connections to the database when you are finished with them?

Comment: Well, the connections are automatically closed by TableAdapter and I'm disposing the TableAdapter itself (TableAdapter.Dispose()) but I'm not sure if it's enough. I now changed the code to Using Statement as it seems to be the recommended way to dispose. So far working normally...

Comment: It didn't help. I see, however, that every time this slowdown occurs the Page life Expectancy drops to 1 until it starts to increase to 40, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 etc. and then everything works fast. I have the SQL profiler running but I don't know what to look for?

Comment: Could this be about the first call to SQL Server or if the query is not found in cache it's slow? But I can't believe it may take 40 seconds?